# Determine how many items rendered from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP MVC view that, at the top of the page has this declaration

```
@model IEnumerable<Monet.Models.AgentTransmission>
```

This view will render a list of type `AgentTranmsission` on the page. However, I would like to display a grid based on whether or not any results were returned. How would I write a conditional, in the view, to do this? Below was my first attempt but that is throwing the error: `Monet.Models.AgentTransmission is a type, which is not valid in this context`

```
@if (Model.Count<Monet.Models.AgentTransmission> 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{

}
```